# SQL Query results WHERE ID IN (@ids) can't convert nvarchar() to int

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am having difficulty solving my problem of selecting records using `WHERE IN ()`. I am working with `C#` in back end where I am sending a comma separated string of `id` values. I am looking to query all records that are in that string.

Here is my sample string:

```
"548,549,550,551,712,713"
```

Here is my `SQL Stored Procedure`

```
@ids nvarchar(200)

SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE USers.ID IN (@ids)
```

**But I get an error:**

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '548, 549, 550,
>   551, 712, 713' to data type int.

Thank you

Comment: `WHERE ID IN('548, 549, 550, 551, 712, 713')` <> `WHERE ID IN(548, 549, 550, 551, 712, 713)`

Comment: Your query is not `ID IN (548,549,550,551,712,713)`, it's `ID IN ('548,549,550,551,712,713')`; you need multiple parameters for multiple values. _Also, MySQL != SQL Server._

Comment: SQL Server does not support macro substitution.  You would either have to go dynamic or parse the string into a record set

Comment: But I never know how many parameters I will be sending to stored procedure. How can I go around that problem? My @ids may contain 1 to many items

Comment: @IamCavic No I will remove my upvote, and you still have 1 dv

Comment: Here you go +1 :)

Comment: Thank you all for being such great community members!!

Comment: +1 from me too as it's been a long day, but check out https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/begging-for-votes

Comment: @stuartd I  get passionate from time to time.. I was not looking for extra votes. I was just disappointed with a -1, I feel that question was not to be categorized as bad! that is all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**SQL Server 2016 and later versions**

```
 Declare @ids nvarchar(200) = '123,456';

 Select *
 From Users
 Where ID  IN ( Select Value from STRING_SPLIT ( @ids , ',' ))
```

**For older versions SQL Server 2005 - 2014**

```
 Declare @ids nvarchar(200) = '123,456'; --<-- Comma delimited list of Client Ids


 Select *
 From Users
 Where ID  IN (
              SELECT  CAST(RTRIM(LTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) AS INT) IDs
              FROM (
                     SELECT Cast ('<X>' 
                                  + Replace(@ids, ',', '</X><X>') 
                                  + '</X>' AS XML) AS Data
                      ) AS t CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/X') AS Split(a) 
                    )
```

Comment: Yeah this worked.. Thank you, I will accept the answer when timer clears!

Comment: I don't know who down voted my question would appreciate at least a 0... anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that a table-valued function that unpacks a comma-separated string of numbers into a table to be very useful:

```
-- =============================================
-- Description: Generates a table of values generated from
--              a given csv list of integer values. Each value
--              in the list is separated by commas. The output
--              table of values has one integer per row. Any non-
--              numeric entries are discarded.
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCSVIntListToTable]
(   
    @CSVList nvarchar(MAX)

)
RETURNS  @Result TABLE(Value int)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Ensure the parameter is not null
    SET @CSVList = ISNULL(@CSVList, '');

    -- Create XML string from the CSV list
    DECLARE @x XML 
      SELECT @x = CAST('<A>'+ REPLACE(@CSVList, ',' , '</A><A>')+ '</A>' AS XML);

    -- Unpack the XML string into the table
    INSERT INTO @Result            
        SELECT t.value('.', 'int') AS inVal
        FROM @x.nodes('/A') AS x(t)

        -- Discard any non-numeric entries
        WHERE ISNUMERIC(t.value('.', 'varchar(20)'))=1


    RETURN
END
```

Then in your procedure code you can use the function directly in a join:

```
 Declare @ids nvarchar(200) = '123,456,789';
 :
 :
 Select *
 From Users UU
 JOIN dbo.fnCSVIntListToTable(@ids)  IDS
  ON IDS.Value = UU.ID;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping however I already implemented the answer above from another SO member. Thank you John!

Comment: Personally I would use a [Table-Valued Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) rather than all this messing about with XML.

Comment: @stuartd - Fair enough, but if the data available to the OP is in the form of a comma-separated string of integers, then it has to be unpacked somewhere/somehow to get it into a table.